# Conflict between utf8 and other packages

Tags: hyperref, babel, input-encodings, lettrine, utf8

Whatever I do I receive this message (`! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence`) when I run `livre.tex`. I assume that livre.tex combined with .sty file doesn't like (Ôter) as a first word in the script because when I put (Ôter) in the middle, it doesn't give the error message and when I run (Ôter) in this little script there is no problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Ôter le 
\end{document}
```

I assume that there is a conflict somewhere and I have no idea what to do. Need help.
Download link
https://gofile.io/d/ekiNkO
Edit link
https://gofile.io/d/ekiNkO/edit

Thanks in advance

Comment: presumably you have not saved the file in UTF-8 but in a legacy encoding such as iso 8859-1, check the settings in your editor.

Comment: If this is the only time this happens: Would `\^{O}ter` work?

Comment: yes (note your edit link is password protected and I choose not to download zip files from unknown sites so I have only seen the small example here) using `\^` would work but saving the file un utf-8 or specifying the correct encoding to inputenc would be better

Comment: The question was kind of rhetorical, but thanks for confirming :-) That said, I agree that UTF-8 is the way to go.